# filling several columns with 0 and 1 (creating dummy variables)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a ms-access 2003 table with exp and imp columns. In these exp and imp columns I have 75 countries. I want to create dummy variables exp1-exp75, imp1-imp75, in the same table, showing which country is exp and which country is imp. So for example if exp is Australia (Australia is the 1st country) then exp1 must be 1 and all other exp2-exp75 should be 0. And if imp is UK (UK is the 5th country), imp5 should be 1 and all the other imp's should be 0. So the table should look like this (if USA is the 3rd and Italy is the 17th country)

```
exp           imp    exp1 exp2 ...exp17 ... exp75 imp1 imp2 imp3 ... imp5 ... imp75


Australia     UK      1    0        0         0     0    0    0        1        0


Italy         USA     0    0        1         0     0    0    1        0        0
```

Thanks.

Comment: What earthly reason do you have for such a horrid table design? I'm assuming you must have one....

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in the Access 2007 editor, but the VBA should be the same. I don't think you can do it with queries.

```
Private Sub FillTable()

Const firstCountry  As Integer = 1
Const lastCountry   As Integer = 75
Const maxRows       As Integer = 234 'or whatever you need...


Dim impCountry  As Integer
Dim expCountry  As Integer

Dim db  As DAO.Database
Dim rs  As DAO.Recordset
Dim i   As Integer

Dim j   As Integer

    'function Random1to75 is left as an exercise for the reader
    impCountry = Random1to75
    expCountry = Random1to75

    Do Until expCountry <> impCountry
        expCountry = Random1to75
    Loop

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from YourTable", dbOpenDynaset)

    For j = 1 To maxRows
        rs.AddNew
            For i = firstCountry To lastCountry
                If i <> impCountry Then
                    rs("imp" & i) = 0
                Else
                    rs("imp" & i) = 1
                End If

                If i <> expCountry Then
                    rs("exp" & i) = 0
                Else
                    rs("exp" & i) = 1
                End If
            Next
        rs.Update
    Next

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```